# How to set element name in pug?

Tags: html, pug

I am trying to set my element name in pug, but in html it converts it into id

Here's what I'm trying to set

```
info-window#window
```

And here is the output in html

```
<info-window id="window">
```

And I am expecting this output

```
<info-window #window">
```

Comment: Surely you don't want `<info-window #window">`, do you? With the one random quote?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you want to achive:

```
h1 But
p Feel free to mix HTML markup ...
<info-window #window>
p ... and pug syntax
```